# Get JSON response from server using form with iFrame, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, yii, yii2

I have a form that contains file upload inputs, I use `iframe` to submit those files and the rest data via `ajax`:

```
<form id="myform" action="/megogo/web/index.php?r=form/create-order" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
            ..inputs, file inputs..
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#"></iframe>
```

I receive data correctly on the server, but I cannot send response status back to the client:

```
public function actionCreateOrder(){
    //gettting data from $_POST
     $status = 1;
    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $status;
}
```

Now when form is submitted I receive:

```
$("#myform").submit( function(e){    

      $.ajax({               
            success: function (response) 
            {    
               console.log(response);
            }
        });

  });
```

I get `html` page for `response` and the message `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:`. How can I access my `status` instead?
I cannot change `enctype` because I will not receive uploaded files then. Id appreciate any advice.

Comment: .ajax looks incomplete and you need to echo json response, not return.

Comment: I post data directly from the form, in `jQuery` script I just want to get response. If I use `$.ajax()` to post `form.serialize()`, I wont receive files.

Comment: I've used this plugin http://www.dropzonejs.com/ to ajax files. works well if that helps. With this tutorial http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot use it. Is there any workaround? Can I change html response, by writing into it on the server?

Comment: making your controller extending `\yii\rest\controller` instead of `\yii\web\controller` won't be an option here ? ([check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056887/how-to-json-encode-in-yii2#answer-35058024))