# how to Json encode in yii2?

Tags: php, json, yii2

Attempting to encode json and receive `400: Bad Request` in `yii2`. I am trying to encode in Rest client but it is not working properly.

```
<?php 
    namespace app\controllers;
    use Yii;
    use yii\filters\AccessControl;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
    use app\models\TblUserRegistration;
    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function actionRegister()
        {
            $model = new TblUserRegistration();
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            echo json_encode($username);
        }
    }
?>
```

Error image.[image]

Error image[image]

Comment: set response format to `\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;`

Comment: Insane is right. Use \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

Comment: add hidden field in form for csrf: ` <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />`

Comment: @InsaneSkull Actually I want to use that in Advance Rest client in google chrome Because i want to use that in web service.So i don't have any form. I just need pure json encoded data.

Comment: Then set  `\Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;` should work for you.

Comment: configure json parser for json output in  configuration.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I think ContentNegotiator will do the trick for one action. I mean maybe he have no needs to set it globally. I guess it is also a csrf issue as mentioned by @suibber which throws the 400 error. setting the controller's public property `$enableCsrfValidation` to false as it is done in `\yii\rest\Controller` may fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** In case if all your controller's actions will deliver json you may also consider extanding [yii\rest\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-controller.html) instead of yii\web\Controller :

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;

class UserController extends \yii\rest\Controller
{
    public function actionRegister()
    {
        $username = Yii::$app->request->post('username');
        return $username;
    }
}
```

*NOTE: you may also use [ActiveController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html) which extends [yii\rest\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-controller.html) (see [rest docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)) if you need to handle CRUD operations.*

---

**Solution 2:**  A different approach when extending [yii\web\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html) is by using [yii\filters\ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html). Note that setting `$enableCsrfValidation` to **false** may be mandatory here as it is explained in its [related docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$enableCsrfValidation-detail) :

> Whether to enable CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) validation.
>   Defaults to true. When CSRF validation is enabled, forms submitted to
>   an Yii Web application must be originated from the same application.
>   If not, a 400 HTTP exception will be raised.
>
> Note, this feature requires that the user client accepts cookie. Also,
>   to use this feature, forms submitted via POST method must contain a
>   hidden input whose name is specified by $csrfParam. You may use
>   yii\helpers\Html::beginForm() to generate his hidden input.

The above code may be rewritten this way :

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'contentNegotiator' => [
                'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],
                'only' => ['register'],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionRegister()
    {
        $username = Yii::$app->request->post('username');
        return $username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $model = new TblUserRegistration();
    return $_POST['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**i think 400 have nothing to do with json_encode**

google "yii2 csrf" for more information.

```js
public function actionRegister()
{
    // is not safe
    Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;

    // set response header
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
  
    $model = new TblUserRegistration();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    return $username;
}
```

or add scrf in view:
form:

```js
<input name="_csrf" type="hidden" id="_csrf" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken ?>">
```

meta:

```js
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
```

Comment: Nice googling about csrf on bad request.

Comment: @suibber Thanks for answer but still it doesn't work.is there need any more config in yii?

Comment: @suibber i have attached image in my question.

Comment: try to use get instead of post ? and i can't see the response body on your image

Comment: @suibber When i use get it throws 500 internal server error.

Comment: because you use $username = $_POST['username']; in controller

Comment: not in YII_DEBUG mode,so there no detail info.you can get error log in /runtimes/logs/app.log