# How to set and return virtual attribute value got from request in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a virtual public attribute in `ActiveRecord` class. When I receive `JSON` `RawBody` in `ActiveController` class I am trying to assign parsed JSON to `$model->attributes`. Request JSON looks like:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "address": "a place on earth",
  "_id": 1
}
```

Now in the above JSON `_id` is the key which I have declared as a `public $_id;` in `ActiveRecord` class also I have used setter getter for this property like this:

```
public function setId ($value) 
{
    $this->_id = $value;
}

public function getId ($value)
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

ActiveController methods:

```
public function actionPush() 
{
    $data = $this->getRequestData();
    $model = new User();
    $model->attributes = $data;

    if($model->save())
        return ['status' => 200, 'message' => 'Record added successfully', 'record' => $model];

    return ['status' => 400, 'message' => 'Records not updated', 'errors' => $errors];
}

public function getRequestData()
{
    $body = \Yii::$app->request->getRawBody();

    $parser = new JsonParser();

    return $parser->parse($body, 'application/json');
}
```

Now I want response like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Record added successfully",
    "record": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "test",
            "_id": 1
        }
}
```

But getting like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Record added successfully",
    "record": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "test"
        }
}
```

How do I achieve the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Case 1 : you want to replace `id` by `_id`

If your model already have an attribute called `id` then I won't be sure if it will be a good practice by design to override an existing DB attribute. I would suggest overriding [yii\base\Model::fields()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#fields()-detail) instead as it is done within the built-in Yii RESTful API ([see docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html)). 
This way you'll keep the original instance of your model to be used whenever needed inside your app and tie `$model->fields()` to user endpoint or output.

I think you don't even need a virtual attribute here. in case if you are planning to manually set or update your model's primary key, then a mapper attribute between `id` and `_id` may be enough. and this could be done within a setter method. Add this to your model :

```
// remember to add '_id' to safe attributes (model::rules)
public function set_id ($value)
{
    $this->id = $value;
}

public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    unset($fields['id']);
    $fields['_id'] = $this->id;
    // or $fields['_id'] = $this->getPrimaryKey();
    return $fields;
}
```

Then force `actionPush()` to return `$model->fields()` instead of `$model` :

```
public function actionPush() 
{
    $data = $this->getRequestData();
    $model = new User();
    $model->attributes = $data;

    if($model->save())
        return [
            'status' => 200, 
            'message' => 'Record added successfully',
            'record' => $model->fields();
        ];

    return ['status' => 400, 'message' => 'Records not updated', 'errors' => $errors];
}
```

---

### Case 2 : you want to keep both `id` and `_id`

I'm adding this 2nd case as I think I may misunderstood your question. if you want to keep and maintain both attributes `id` and `_id` :

```
"record": {
   "id": 10,
   "_id": 1
   "name": "test",
}
```

Then this will do the trick :

```
private $_id;

public function get_id ()
{
    return $this->_id;
}

public function set_id ($value)
{
    $this->_id = $value;
}

public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields['_id'] = '_id';
    return $fields;
}
```

NOTE: `fields` will be used by Yii to retrieve attributes in case if [\yii\web\Response](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html) is set to `\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON` (*this can be set in config file or within [ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html)*). Otherwise if you are using different formatters, then you may manually invoke `$model->fields()` instead of `$model` to output data.

Comment: My expected case is second one, also I had tried something like this but it was giving error. But let me try once I surely get you the result

Comment: I tried this but giving `"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_id' in 'field list'` error

Comment: mmm I see. I just found [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1967). it seems not good idea to merge with `attributes`. `fields` should be fine in case if you are using Json formatter. i will update my answer.

Comment: done. tell me please if it worked. an exemple with contentNegotiator may be foud [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056887/how-to-json-encode-in-yii2/35058024#35058024) in case you are not already using `\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON`.

Comment: Thanks @salem-ouerdani it worked like charm and thanks for nice explanation, in my case I am using `\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON`.